# Bootstrap - Tabs on both sides?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm trying to have one tab which will float right rather than float left like the other tabs

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills ">
          <li class="floatLeft active"><a href="#Overview" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
          <li class="floatLeft"><a href="#Excursions" data-toggle="tab">Excursions</a></li>
          <li class="floatLeft"><a href="#Speakers" data-toggle="tab">Speakers</a></li>

          <li class="floatRight"><a href="#Fares" data-toggle="tab">Fares</a></li>
       </ul>
```

Simple css class wouldn't work. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class names are incorrect, try this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills ">
    <li class="active"><a href="#Overview" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Excursions" data-toggle="tab">Excursions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Speakers" data-toggle="tab">Speakers</a></li>
    <li class="pull-right"><a href="#Fares" data-toggle="tab">Fares</a></li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: To give an explanation of the changes I have made. The class names for floating left and right in bootstrap are `pull-left` and `pull-right` I applied t`pull-right` to the final nav to float it to the right. I also removed the class from the first 3, because navs already floated left by default, so they did not need to be there.

Comment: I have just made them up and forgot to enclose them properly (corrected now). Anyway, your solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks